# trouble working around type<seq<seq<int>>?

Tags: function, f#, sequence

I have defined two function with collatz sequences

a sequence for an initial n

```
let rec collatzz n =   seq { 
    yield n 
    if n%2=0 then yield! collatzz (n/2) else yield! collatzz (n*3+1)
    }

let rec collatz n = 
    match n with
    |n when n<0 -> failwith"Please use a positive integer"
    |_ -> collatzz n
```

```
val collatzz: n: int -> seq<int>
val collatz: n: int -> seq<int>
```

and another sequence that contains a sequence of all n's

```
let  collatzSequences= Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> collatz (i+1))
```

```
val collatzSequences: seq<seq<int>>
```

Now i'am trying to define a function that will tell the stopping time(index) of each sequence, or the first accurence of the number 1 in each sequence.

So far i can do this over 1 index at a time but i'am kinda stuck on how to that for all the sequences

```
collatz 1 |> Seq.findIndex (fun i -> i=1)
```

and of course if i try to

```
collatzSequences |> Seq.findIndex (fun i -> i=1)
```

it won't work because it's a seq of seq and i don't how to "split" it in function

Answer (score 1):

The way to transform every element of a sequence in a certain way is called `map`

When every element of the sequence is another sequence, and the way you want to transform it is `findIndex`, you would do:

```
let findOne s = s |> Seq.findIndex (fun i -> i=1)

collatzSequences |> Seq.map findOne
```

Or inline, without giving the function a name:

```
collatzSequences |> Seq.map (fun s -> s |> Seq.findIndex (fun i -> i=1))
```